# Type mismatch error only happens on remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, tfs, model

My code works fine in dev, but when I publish to a test server, one screen is giving an error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Intranet.ViewModels.EditingRequestsViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Intranet.ViewModels.ITRequestsViewModel]'.

This is the controller code, and as intended, it uses the EditingRequestsViewModel:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var myList = db.Database.SqlQuery<EditingRequestsViewModel>("EXEC [DBO].[spGetRequests]").ToList();
       return View(myList);
    }
```

And here is the first line of the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Intranet.ViewModels.EditingRequestsViewModel>
```

Why would this same code expect a different model when published to a test server? I've tried "Clean Solution," "Rebuild Solution," deleting the Dlls, and redeploying (repeatedly) using both debug and release configurations. No change.

I should remark that, before this started, I checked my code into TFS and had a conflict where I took the server version of my Project file. This caused some issues with this "editing" controller not being seen (it was new) but I fixed that and everything works fine in dev.

Is there a hidden reference in a file, that might be jacked up?

Comment: Add .AsEnumerable() after the .ToList() in your function.. ugly but worth a shot

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you post stack trace of that error? Since it only occurs on test server, probably something weird happen in test server which isn't appear on dev machine.

Comment: Can it work directly on the test server? I mean just copy it to test server to run.

Answer (score 0):

Just try try to change

```
 @model IEnumerable<Intranet.ViewModels.EditingRequestsViewModel>
```

to

```
@model List<Intranet.ViewModels.EditingRequestsViewModel>
```

Comment: @Geminirand  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List , but used model IEnumerable in the view . So, just try to change it back.